# Where is PHP selenium testing documentaiton

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit

In my new project I was asked to check selenium and phpUnit testing which I never did before. I encountered some function like `byCssSelector`, `byId`, `acceptAlert` and many more. I found some functions in https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/index.html which are related to phpUnit testing. But I could not find the definitions of functions related to selenium testing. For example, I tried `byCssSelector` and could not find its documentation anywhere. In which documentation these functions are described?

Comment: What PHP library are you using to drive Selenium? I believe Facebook's `WebDriver` is good, and the autocomplete you get from that in your IDE should help.

Answer (score 2):

On [`http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/`](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/) you'll find the official documentation. Just select `PHP` as your programming language preference.

The PHP bindings are made by third parties and you are [referred](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#php) to their respective documentations. The [binding](https://facebook.github.io/php-webdriver/) offered by Facebook seems to offer extensive [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/php-webdriver/).